# Implementation of Array data type in OCaml

Tags: arrays, types, ocaml

I have very little knowledge about OCaml as a whole and just received an assignment to take one of the source files in the project and allow it to take a new data type (Array). I am not asking for someone to solve this problem for me, but instead I would appreciate someone walking me through this code. I would also appreciate any input on how difficult it is going to be to implement this new data type.

The file itself lacks a lot of documentation which doesn't make it any easier either.

```
(* * Types (hashconsed) *)

(* ** Imports *)
open Abbrevs
open Util

(* ** Identifiers *)

module Lenvar : (module type of Id) = Id

module Tysym : (module type of Id) = Id

module Groupvar : (module type of Id) = Id

module Permvar : (module type of Id) = Id


(* ** Types and type nodes *)

type ty = {
  ty_node : ty_node;
  ty_tag : int
}
and ty_node =
  | BS of Lenvar.id
  | Bool
  | G of Groupvar.id
  | TySym of Tysym.id
  | Fq
  | Prod of ty list
  | Int

(* ** Equality, hashing, and hash consing *)

let equal_ty : ty -> ty -> bool = (==)
let hash_ty t = t.ty_tag
let compare_ty t1 t2 = t1.ty_tag - t2.ty_tag

module Hsty = Hashcons.Make (struct
  type t = ty

  let equal t1 t2 =
    match t1.ty_node, t2.ty_node with
    | BS lv1, BS lv2                 -> Lenvar.equal lv1 lv2
    | Bool, Bool                     -> true
    | G gv1, G gv2                   -> Groupvar.equal gv1 gv2
    | TySym ts1, TySym ts2           -> Tysym.equal ts1 ts2
    | Fq, Fq                         -> true
    | Prod ts1, Prod ts2             -> list_eq_for_all2 equal_ty ts1 ts2
    | _                              -> false

  let hash t =
    match t.ty_node with
    | BS lv         -> hcomb 1 (Lenvar.hash lv)
    | Bool          -> 2
    | G gv          -> hcomb 3 (Groupvar.hash gv)
    | TySym gv      -> hcomb 4 (Tysym.hash gv)
    | Fq            -> 5
    | Prod ts       -> hcomb_l hash_ty 6 ts
    | Int           -> 7

  let tag n t = { t with ty_tag = n }
end)

(** Create [Map], [Set], and [Hashtbl] modules for types. *)
module Ty = StructMake (struct
  type t = ty
  let tag = hash_ty
end)
module Mty = Ty.M
module Sty = Ty.S
module Hty = Ty.H

(* ** Constructor functions *)

let mk_ty n = Hsty.hashcons {
  ty_node = n;
  ty_tag  = (-1)
}

let mk_BS lv = mk_ty (BS lv)

let mk_G gv = mk_ty (G gv)

let mk_TySym ts = mk_ty (TySym ts)

let mk_Fq = mk_ty Fq

let mk_Bool = mk_ty Bool

let mk_Int = mk_ty Int

let mk_Prod tys =
  match tys with
  | [t] -> t
  | _   -> mk_ty (Prod tys)

(* ** Indicator and destructor functions *)

let is_G ty = match ty.ty_node with
  | G _ -> true
  | _   -> false

let is_Fq ty = match ty.ty_node with
  | Fq -> true
  | _  -> false

let is_Prod ty = match ty.ty_node with
  | Prod _ -> true
  | _      -> false

let destr_G_exn ty =
  match ty.ty_node with
  | G gv -> gv
  | _    -> raise Not_found

let destr_BS_exn ty =
  match ty.ty_node with
  | BS lv -> lv
  | _     -> raise Not_found

let destr_Prod_exn ty =
  match ty.ty_node with
  | Prod ts -> ts
  | _       -> raise Not_found

let destr_Prod ty =
  match ty.ty_node with
  | Prod ts -> Some ts
  | _       -> None

(* ** Pretty printing *)

let pp_group fmt gv =
  if Groupvar.name gv = ""
  then F.fprintf fmt "G"
  else F.fprintf fmt "G_%s" (Groupvar.name gv)

let rec pp_ty fmt ty =
  match ty.ty_node with
  | BS lv             -> F.fprintf fmt "BS_%s" (Lenvar.name lv)
  | Bool              -> F.fprintf fmt "Bool"
  | Fq                -> F.fprintf fmt "Fq"
  | TySym ts          -> F.fprintf fmt "%s" (Tysym.name ts)
  | Prod ts           -> F.fprintf fmt "(%a)" (pp_list " * " pp_ty) ts
  | Int               -> F.fprintf fmt "Int"
  | G gv ->
    if Groupvar.name gv = ""
    then F.fprintf fmt "G"
    else F.fprintf fmt "G_%s" (Groupvar.name gv)
```

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you asked a specific question. There's too much going on it this code to walk through it here, especially without some guidance about what you are wanting to understand about it.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I apologize. I am still very new to this language. So, in order to create a function to read and write arrays, would I have to create a module for that array to keep its length and allow it to be indexed?

Comment: The code you give above doesn't deal with data (reading and writing data, for example). It provides a convenient and efficient representation of types. I would assume that "adding arrays" to this would mean to support an array type in a similar way. So your question doesn't make sense (to me) in the context of the source file above. If you want to read and write arrays *in OCaml* (for whatever reason) you don't need a module for this. An array keeps track of its own length (`Array.length a`), and you can index one with an int expression (`a.(my_index)`).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Yes, I am trying to add support for array type in this source file. I'm sorry if I am making this more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: (I added an update, see my answer. It's guesswork, but probably worth something as a suggestion.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to walk through this code because quite a bit is missing (definitions of Id, Hashcons, StructMake). But in general this code manipulates data structures that represent types.

You can read about hash consing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing (which is what I just did myself). In essence it is a way of maintaining a canonical representation for a set of structures (in this case, structures representing types) so that two structures that are equal (having constituents that are equal) are represented by the identical value. This allows constant-time comparison for equality. When you do this with strings, it's called "interning" (a technique from Lisp I've used many times).

To add arrays, you need to know whether the array type will include the length of the array or just the type of its elements. The semi-mysterious type `BS` seems to include a length, which suggests you may want to include the length in your reprsentation.

If I were doing this project I would look for every occurence of `Prod` (which represents tuples) and I'd add a type representing `Array` in an analogous way. Instead of a list of constituent types (as for a tuple) you have one constituent type and (I would guess) a variable representing the length of the array.

Before starting out I'd look for some documentation, on what `BS` represents for one thing. I also have no idea what "groups" are, but maybe you could worry about it later.

**Update**

Here's what I mean by copying `Prod`. Keep in mind that I am basing this almost entirely on guesswork. So, many details (or even the entire idea) could be wrong.

The current definition of a type looks like this:

```
and ty_node =
  | BS of Lenvar.id
  | Bool
  | G of Groupvar.id
  | TySym of Tysym.id
  | Fq
  | Prod of ty list
  | Int
```

If you add a representation for `Array` after `Prod` you get something like this:

```
and ty_node =
  | BS of Lenvar.id
  | Bool
  | G of Groupvar.id
  | TySym of Tysym.id
  | Fq
  | Prod of ty list
  | Array of Lenvar.id * ty
  | Int
```

You would then go through the rest of the code adding support for the new `Array` variant. The compiler will help you find many of the places that need fixing.

Comment: The project itself is a research project on automated cryptography proofs. I got hired as an intern, but the position they put me in is very difficult considering the resources they gave me. With that being said this comment helps a lot. 

From what I can gather BS might stand for "bit string" so it could possibly be implemented similar to those?

Comment: Yes, I figured `BS` stood for bit string. The type system implemented in your source code appears to keep a symbolic representation of the length of the bit string (it uses a variable to represent the length). So you probably want to use a similar symbolic representation of the length of an array.

Comment: (Pardon me for speaking out of turn, but you should find a mentor on the project. Many of the things you need to learn are not properties of OCaml the language but rather are conventions and practices of this particular project. FWIW, the code as given above looks very excellent.)

Comment: @Jeffery Scofield The thing is, I got hired as an intern for one of the professors at my university. Sadly, I am the only intern, and she doesn't fully understand OCaml or the program either. She just does the math for it. So, I really have no documentation, no guidance, and no way of getting help. This is why I may be coming off as desperate. I have to get this code working by monday and I still have no luck making it compile.